# How can i find all empty catch with resharper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, resharper

I know that there is the possibility to use search pattern but I don't know how to implement this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark any code in Visual Studio and then click, for example the empty try-catch, then go

- Extensions -> Resharper -> Find -> Search with pattern

Now resharper created a pattern for you matching that code:

```
try
{
$statement$
}
catch ($Exception$ $e$)
{
}
```

[image: reshaper find pattern]

You can edit it or add new placeholders and save it, then click Find.

In this case it might be a good idea to add another pattern that matches also empty catch blocks that have no `Exception` parameter:

```
try
{
$statement$
}
catch
{
}
```

By the way, this matches also if the catch contains comments like

```
// don't do anything
```